# Firefox: how to debug SSL error

Tags: firefox, ssl

I am behind a firewall that uses SSL interception. I have installed the CA certificate of the proxy in Firefox, and most SSL connections are established correctly. However, in same cases the connection fails with

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> The connection to jupyter.readthedocs.org was interrupted while the
>   page was loading.
>
> - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> - Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

There is no button to add an exception, nor to get further details on what is wrong.

If I attempt to open the same URL in Chromium (also with the proxy CA certificate installed), everything works fine and Chromium considers the connection secure.

How can I get Firefox to give me more information about what it thinks is wrong with the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get Firefox to give me more information about what it thinks is wrong with the connection?

Probably you can't. If the connection was interrupted than all Firefox knows is the the other end interrupted the connection. There is no indication at the network layer which tells Firefox why the connection was interrupted.

But since there is a firewall with SSL interception the chances are high that the firewall interrupted the connection and you need to look at the firewall logs and configuration to get the reason for the interruption.